# how to ad image in baloon in google map

Tags: android

i found this link http://crazyandroidian.blogspot.com/2011/10/custom-mapview-popup-in-android.html   from google map  but how do i insert image in baloom popup? please help me how do i show image in bubble ? this example just show selected point text how i modify this code  and add image also?

```
     package mapviewballoons.example;

   import java.util.List;

  import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
  import android.os.Bundle;

   import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
  import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MyMap extends MapActivity {

MapView mapView;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
Drawable drawable2;
MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 // first overlay
 drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
 itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
 GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(51.5174723*1E6),(int)(-0.0899537*1E6));
 OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "Umar Shafique", 
 "(here goes 1)");
 itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
 GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.515259*1E6),(int)(-0.086623*1E6)); 

 OverlayItem overlayItem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Abdul Karim", 
 "here goes 2");
 itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem2);
 mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
 // second overlay
 drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker2);
 itemizedOverlay2 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable2, mapView);
 GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.513329*1E6),(int)(-0.08896*1E6));
 OverlayItem overlayItem3 = new OverlayItem(point3, "Arslan Ilyas", 
 "here goes 3");
 itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItem3);
  GeoPoint point4 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.51738*1E6),(int)(-0.08186*1E6));
 OverlayItem overlayItem4 = new OverlayItem(point4, "Ahsan", 
 "here goes 4");
 itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItem4);
 mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);
 final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
 mc.animateTo(point2);
 mc.setZoom(16);
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
 return false;
  }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try Polaris:

http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=824

Using maps and setting pictures in the baloon has never been so easy!